# Assignment for a variable defined whose type is an interface

Tags: java, interface

Any suitable real time example for this statement...?

If you define a reference variable whose type is an interface, any object you assign to it must be an instance of a class that implements the interface.

Comment: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()`? Any real Java program has that kind of example every 10 line of code or so.

Comment: @JBNizet It is correct, though I think generics seems distracted the the focus

Comment: What is the meaning of "Real time" example? Or do you mean "Real life"?  What do you mean by "real life" then?

Comment: @AdrianShum Real time only happens in real life...!! Dont you think so..?

Comment: Nele, real time is when we have a running application and we have some activity , a simple example as injecting dependencies via some external file. Real life need not be real time. You can have static dependencies during compilation it self  Real time is more related to run time.

Comment: "Real time" is a term of art in computer engineering meaning that there is a bounded response time for interactions. "Real life" has nothing to do with anything. It is not merely a "running application" with "some activity". "Real time" is a term and concept you can easily look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interface` defines  a **contract**. Contract defines a set of rules. `interface` defines rules by declaring the methods (their signature : input parameter, return type , name, and  also maybe sometimes some constraints as written in java docs for the implementation).

A reference variable declared of the type of some `interface` can only refer to the Objects of the class which adhers to the rules set in the contract as defined by that particular interface.

By reference variable we can invoke the methods on the object. Suppose the interface sets some method in its declaration and then we have a variable of type of that interface. Now those set methods should be able to be invoked by that variable. To do so it is mandatory that it only refers the object of the class implementing that particular interface.

By implementing an interface a concrete class ( non abstract) is bound to provide the implementation of the rules (methods) set by the Contract (interface).

```
List x = new ArrayList();// valid
List y = new LinkedList();// valid 
List z = new StringBuffer(); // invalid as StringBuffer does not implements List interface.
```

Comment: Did you mean `interface`?

Comment: You had it as `Interface`. The upper-case "I" would cause a compiler failure.

Comment: @Lew Bloch, I meant by Interface the noun for explaing the underlying concept just like we use *classes* though there is no such keyword, we should use more than one `class`. But still its valid so I replaced `I` with `i`.

Comment: Make sure when you mark up text as a keyword that you mean to do so.

Comment: @Lew Bloch, yes I corrected, valid point when marking up a text as code then it should be as per the valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StackOverflowQuestion {

    private final List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addAnswer(Answer answer) {
        answers.add(answer);
    }
}
```

Here the class `ArrayList<T>` implements the interface `List<T>`.